# Calculate ID based on ID from another field

Tags: qgis, calculate-values

I have a layer with single lines and I have added a unique ID for each line. I have extracted the vertices of these lines to a new point layer and now I want to add a new ID for every point but based on the ID of the line. This is an example of what I want.

[image]

Any idea about how to calculate field "ID_vert" with QGIS (preferably)?

Comment: If you added an ID to your lines and then use the `extract vertices` tool in QGIS 3.10, a "line wise" ID is added to your points automatically - so you get what you say you need. Which version of QGIS are you working with?

Comment: Are you aware that if you join each line with its vertices n-times you will have n-lines in end? Will it be okay for you? What does your end geometry should look like, lines or multilines?

Comment: Check what @Erik has mentioned, `'Extract vertices'` tool should be in the Processing Toolbox?

Comment: I wanted exactly what Erik mentioned. I had extracted the vertices with a different software so I didn't have that index in the attribute table. Just made it again with QGIS and there it was!